# Pictures not changing opacity when I hover over the element with :hover

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to make it possible to hover over an image, which causes two more images to appear (they change opacity from 0 to 1). But for some reason it doesnt work. It is possible to do without jquery, so please try to help me with css/html.

HTML:

```
 <a href="#">
<img src="gaspari/portret.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;">
</a>
<img class="prikaz" src="gaspari/slike.jpg"   width="300px;"height="300px;">
<img class="prikaz" src="gaspari/kip.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;">
```

CSS:

```
 .prikaz {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.9s linear;
  }
  a:hover .prikaz {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: `a:hover ~ .prikaz` does it. `.pikiraz` is a sibling and not a descendant of `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a:hover .prikaz` will select any element with the class `prikaz` that is a descendant of an `<a>`, of which your example has zero. You want to use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) instead, `~`.

```
 a:hover ~ .prikaz {
   opacity: 1;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```css
 .prikaz {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.9s linear;
 }
 
 a:hover ~ .prikaz {
   opacity: 1;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" width="300px;" height="300px;">
</a>
<img class="prikaz" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" width="300px;" height="300px;">
<img class="prikaz" src="http://www.placehold.it/300x300" width="300px;" height="300px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

`a:hover  .prikaz` is a descendant selector, while `a:hover ~ .prikaz` is a general sibling selector.

```css
 .prikaz {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.9s linear;
  }
  a:hover ~ .prikaz {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  object-fit:cover;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
<img src="https://www.thetelugufilmnagar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Samantha.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;">
</a>
<img class="prikaz" src="http://tollypop.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Arthana-4-683x1024.jpg"   width="300px;"height="300px;">
<img class="prikaz" src="http://www.gulte.com/content/2012/04/news/Hot-Tamannah-practical-outlook-on-Heroines---1018.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;">
```

Comment: Never heard of sibling selectors, thank you very much :)